# Ubuntu SDK conflicts with Amarok

Tags: apt, kde, dependencies, amarok, ubuntu-sdk

Apt removed Amarok after installing Ubuntu SDK due to dependencies conflict.
Now when I try to reinstall it again i get this message

```
is7yx@is7yx-Satellite-L305:~$ sudo apt-get install amarok
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amarok : Depends: amarok-common (= 2:2.6.0-0ubuntu2) but 2:2.6.0-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
          Depends: amarok-utils (= 2:2.6.0-0ubuntu2) but 2:2.6.0-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
          Recommends: media-player-infoxs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: In general yes, but not specifically to the new Ubuntu SDK. Thank you though Mr. Carvalho.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try installing the newest amarok version from their ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install amarok
```

If you're lucky it will work and on top of that you have the new Amarok 2.7 which I think has some nice new features :-) You might have to do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying to install Amarok.

If it doesn't work you can easily remove the ppa again:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```